# How to get the list of all the plugin projects using java?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have created around 20 plugin projects.
Since I want to know the version of all those plugin projects, I need the list of all those plugins first.
Can some one guide me how can I get that list of plugins programmatically? Or Do I need to hardcode all the plugins names to get their version?

Comment: Programmatically within your Eclipse RCP application? Like _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_? If yes, look how Eclipse does it.

Comment: I meant the plugins which I created, how can I get that list by java code?

Comment: or lets say I have created a feature project called a.test which is having all the plugins in its feature.xml, how can I search that feature project with java code so that I can get the plugins from its fetaure.xml?

Comment: Programmatically inside or outside your Eclipse RCP application? Please [tell also why you want to do this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: This depends a lot on exactly what you are doing. For example, an RCP using "p2"  can get details of a feature through p2 APis, an RCP which doesn't use p2 (such as a pure e4 RCP) can't easily get details of a feature.

Comment: Thanks, I have got the list from Activator.